# 'pub get' has not been run flutter error. Clicked on get dependencies still getting a error.What shall i do?

Tags: ios, flutter, iosdeployment

'pub get' has not been run flutter error.Clicked on get dependencies still getting a error
It,s showing process finished with exit code 65.

I tried many times by clicking on Get dependencies still it,s not working and my app is not running.

Comment: run `flutter pub get -v` and edit your question and show us the error from that command